# Aura attribute as type object - not calling its fields with __c at the end

Tags: aura, aura-attribute

I am editing someone else's code, having trouble understanding the below code. Here **creativeRequest** is as type object, but its fields are called without __c at the end. I have added a new field to that object, but not able to access it from aura.

Below is the declaration and how one of its fields are accessed in aura:

```
<aura:attribute name="creativeRequest" type="Object"/>//declaration

<lightning:formattedRichText value="{!v.creativeRequest.TranslationLanguage}"></lightning:formattedRichText>//field access, works!
<lightning:formattedRichText value="{!v.creativeRequest.What_Request__c}"></lightning:formattedRichText>//accessing the field I added to the object, doesn't work.
```

**Update [Apex Setup]**

I guess I figured it out, but now I get this error:
**sobject row was retrieved via soql without querying the requested field Creative_Request__c.What_Request__c**

I get this error message when I add this line to my model:
**this.WhatRequest = creativeRequest.What_Request__c;**

Here how I have the apex code setup:

```
@AuraEnabled
  public static SimpleCreativeRequest getCreativeRequest(Id creativeRequestId) {
    Creative_Request__c creativeRequest = [
      SELECT Id, Name, What_Request__c FROM Creative_Request__c WHERE Id = :creativeRequestId
    ];
}
  public class SimpleCreativeRequest {
    @AuraEnabled public String Id { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled public String Name { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled public String WhatRequest { get; set; }

    public SimpleCreativeRequest() {}
    public SimpleCreativeRequest(Creative_Request__c creativeRequest, Id creativeContentDocumentId, Id creativeRequestContentDocumentId) {
      this.Id = creativeRequest.Id;
      this.Name = creativeRequest.Name;
      this.WhatRequest = creativeRequest.What_Request__c;
    }
  }
```

Appreciate the help.

Comment: You'll need to check the Apex controller, Aura controller, and Aura helper to figure out why it's not working.

Comment: @sfdcfox I have added some more code to the post. I guess I was able to figure it out, but still stuck with an issue. Please have a look at the original post and advice. Thanks

Comment: Where are you actually running constructor for SimpleCreativeRequest? getCreativeREquest method only run SOQL and doest not return SimpleCreativeRequest therefore it won't even deploy as there would be an error

Comment: Thanks @user1974566, that was a simple mistake, I got it fixed a few minutes ago, was not referencing this field at another location, that is why I have been getting this error message.